# Efficient way to select one from each category - Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I'm developing a simple app to return a random selection of `exercises`, one for each `bodypart`.

`bodypart` is an indexed `enum` column on an `Exercise` model. DB is PostgreSQL.

The below achieves the result I want, but feels horribly inefficient (hitting the db once for every `bodypart`):

```
BODYPARTS = %w(legs core chest back shoulders).freeze

@exercises = BODYPARTS.map do |bp|
  Exercise.public_send(bp).sample
end.shuffle
```

So, this gives a random `exercise` for each `bodypart`, and mixes up the order at the end.

I could also store all exercises in memory and select from them; however, I imagine this would scale horribly (there are only a dozen or so seed records at present).

```
@exercises = Exercise.all

BODYPARTS.map do |bp|
  @exercises.select { |e| e[:bodypart] == bp }.sample
end.shuffle
```

Benchmarking these shows the `select` approach as the more effective on a small scale:

```
Queries:            0.072902   0.020728   0.093630 (  0.088008)
Select:             0.000962   0.000225   0.001187 (  0.001113)
MrYoshiji's answer: 0.000072   0.000008   0.000080 (  0.000072)
```

My question is whether there's an efficient way to achieve this output, and, if so, what that approach might look like. Ideally, I'd like to keep this to a single db query.

Happy to compose this using ActiveRecord or directly in SQL. Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try the following: `Exercise.group(:bodypart).select('distinct on (bodypart) *').order('bodypart, random())`;

Comment: Star @MrYoshiji - I had to add `:id` to the group clause, i.e. `Exercise.group(:bodypart, :id).select('distinct on (bodypart) *').order('bodypart, random()')` to overcome the following error: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "exercises.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`. I'll plug it into the bench mark code and see how it compares, but that looks just the ticket - happy to accept your answer if you pop one in!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my comment, you should be able to do (thanks PostgreSQL's `DISTINCT ON`):

```
Exercise.select('distinct on (bodypart) *')
        .order('bodypart, random()')
```

Comment: Thanks again - I've added your approach to the benchmark in the question, and it's also incredibly fast.

Comment: @SRack Databases are always better at dealing with that kind of things ;)

Comment: Yep, that was my hope :) Just had a play and -- correct me if I'm wrong -- you can actually shave a little more off by omitting the grouping: `Exercise.select('distinct on (bodypart) *').order('bodypart, RANDOM()')`.

Answer (score 2):

Postgres' `DISTINCT ON` is very handy and [performance is typically great, too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/34715134#34715134) - for *many* distinct bodyparts with *few* rows each. But for only ***few*** distinct values of `bodypart` with *many* rows each (big table - and your use case) there are far superior query techniques.

This will be *massively* faster in such a case:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM   unnest(enum_range(null::bodypart)) b(bodypart)
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT *
   FROM   exercises
   WHERE  bodypart = b.bodypart
   -- ORDER BY ??? -- for a deterministic pick
   LIMIT  1        -- arbitrary pick!
   ) e;
```

Assuming that `bodypart` is the name of the enum as well as the table column.

`enum_range` is an [*enum support function*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-enum.html) that (quoting the manual):

> Returns all values of the input enum type in an ordered array

I unnest it and run a `LATERAL` subquery for each value, which is *very* fast when supported with the right index. Detailed explanation for the query technique and the needed index (focus on chapter *"2a. LATERAL join"*):

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)

For just an arbitrary row for each `bodypart`, a simple index on `exercises(bodypart)` does the job. But you can have a deterministic pick like "the latest entry" with the right multicolumn index and a matching `ORDER BY` clause and almost the same performance.
Related:

- [Is it a bad practice to query pg_type for enums on a regular basis?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/198789/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-query-pg-type-for-enums-on-a-regular-basis/198817#198817)
- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Comment: Can't compete with that, +1

Comment: This looks fantastic and I'll definitely be doing the recommended reading; _however_, I can't get it working. Is it due to ambiguity in my question, in that the `bodypart` column is a Rails enum column, down as an integer in the db? Thanks very much and +1 for the answer regardless @ErwinBrandstetter.

Comment: @SRack: I have been assuming an actual [Postgres `enum`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-enum.html) data type. But that's not the core of the answer. *Any* cheap way to get the list of distinct bodyparts to work with is good ...

Comment: Great - will have a good look at this tomorrow. Really appreciate the answer.

Comment: If you do not have the definitive list of bodyparts somewhere in the DB (you probably do), you can even do without it. Refer to the [chapter "1. No separate table with unique users" in the related answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)

Comment: I didn't @ErwinBrandstetter - but please don't take that as a lack of appreciation for your answer. I've learned a _lot_ reading through it and the links provided. To be honest, as someone regularly reliant on Active Record's magical helpers, this is far advanced of my knowledge on the subject. Thanks again though.